# PeerCoin Pool Payout Issue

Tags: peercoin

I've got a PeerCoin pool which was working great, and I realized that I didn't set the confirmations to 520, but instead I had them set to 120 and now I've got a message stating the following:

We are investingating issues in the backend. Your shares and hashrate are safe and we will fix things ASAP.

Payouts disabled, you will not receive any coins to your offline wallet for the time being

I've found a block.  I went back and set the confirmations to 520 in both the MPOS and stratum server config files.  I rebooted the server but I'm still getting the message because I think that the payouts where run with the wrong confirmations.  How can I reset this so that payouts will run again with the confirmations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, I'm not all that familiar with peercoin, but I don't get your question, sorry. I assume you are participating in a pool and not running one? What is that number of confirmations you are talking about, is that some kind of difficulty for shares in peercoin? Perhaps it would be the easiest to inquire the pool operator for more information; otherwise I think you may need to clarify your question a bit more.

Comment: no actually it is my pool.  the confirmations for a block on PeerCoin is 520.  My pool was set to 120 confirmations.

Comment: Is that number the maturation period? Also, from whom did you receive a message, if you are the operator of the pool?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the maturation period, but I got the message when I logged into my MPOS console as administrator